# Laravel5 Using JSON & Seeder to feed database

Tags: php, json, database, laravel

Im trying to work with the useful seeding function of laravel to populate tables with custom data. Instead of using Faker Im using Seeder. Consequently I Create a:

1. ‘/json/’ folder and put my JSON data files in there.
2. Finally, in the seeder I mapped the data to JSON object attributes.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JsonTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $json = File::get("/json/cell-1.json");
        $data = json_decode($json);
        $array1 = $data->toArray();
        foreach ($array1['products'] as $obj) {
            DB::table('products')->insert(array(
                'id' => $obj->id,
                'name' => $obj->productName,
                'sku' => $obj->productSku
            ));
            foreach ($data['relatedProducts'] as $obj) {
                DB::table('products_related')->insert(array(
                    'sku' => $obj->sku
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I receive many different errors eg:

- Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()
- Cannot use object of type stdClass as array  (if I dont use         $array1 = $data->toArray(); and use directly $data.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Can I know, where did you put your json file? I can not seed my json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$data is a plain object not a laravel collection so it does not have toArray on it. You can type cast your object to an array by doing below

```
$array1 = (array) $data;
```

Answer (score 4):

`json_decode` will return an object by default. If you want to work with arrays, just use `$assoc = true`.

`$data = json_decode($json, true);`

From the docs:

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

http://php.net/json_decode